# Saving model when using trainer pattern

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm writing fAnoGAN using tf-keras.
And, I implemented below class to train the encoder.
(This class is based on [text](https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/trainer_pattern/))

```
class IZITrainer(keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, encoder, wgan, **kwargs):
    super(IZITrainer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.encoder = encoder
    self.wgan = wgan
```

I have no idea to create ModelCheckpoint that save only encoder model.
I want to know how to save encoder model on model.fit()

I tried to save IZITrainer model but it is not match my desire.
I want to save encoder model only every 10 epochs.